# python selenium chrome driver page not loading successfully

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

It happened strange that when I using selenium to access to a specific web page and the web page did not load into the content. While, the other web pages are completely fine....

Any one have clues on that? Just when I enter in the address bar, it can load again....

Sample screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFJkV.png)

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--verbose')
options.add_argument("window-size=1920x1080")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=options)
driver.get("https://web1.sasa.com/SasaWeb/tch/product/searchProduct.jspa?brandId=28034")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me, just copy the current url, and get the same web page again. Dont know why

```
url = driver.current_url
driver.get(url)
```